# kendo ui grid not showing data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying to get this basic kendo ui with expandable rows working:

```
<div id="grid"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [
            {
                field: "ProductId",
                title: "ProductId"
            }
        ],
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: '@Url.Action("GetData1", "MockForms")'
                }
            },
            height: 450,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            detailTemplate: "<h2 style='background-color: yellow;'>Expanded!</h2>",
            detailExpand: function (e) {
                this.collapseRow(this.tbody.find(' > tr.k-master-row').not(e.masterRow));
            }
        });
    });  
</script>
```

The json is generated like this:

```
public ActionResult GetData1([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var list = new List<Product>
                {
                    new Product {ProductId = 1, ProductType = "SomeType 1", Name = "Name 1", Created = DateTime.UtcNow},
                    new Product {ProductId = 1, ProductType = "SomeType 2", Name = "Name 2", Created = DateTime.UtcNow},
                    new Product {ProductId = 1, ProductType = "SomeType 3", Name = "Name 3", Created = DateTime.UtcNow}
                };

            return Json(list.AsQueryable().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

and seems to be send OK (according to firebug). However, nothing is bound (there are no javascript errors). Any ideas?

PS:

OnaBai's 2nd comment helped me to get this to work. I changed:

```
return Json(list.AsQueryable().ToDataSourceResult(request));
=>
return Json(list);
```

which produces this JSON:

```
[{"ProductId":1,"ProductType":"SomeType 1","Name":"Name 1","Created":"\/Date(1371022051570)\/"},{"ProductId":1,"ProductType":"SomeType 2","Name":"Name 2","Created":"\/Date(1371022051570)\/"},{"ProductId":1,"ProductType":"SomeType 3","Name":"Name 3","Created":"\/Date(1371022051570)\/"}]
```

Still I would like to use:

```
return Json(list.AsQueryable().ToDataSourceResult(request));
```

as this will eventually make paging and sorting easier. It currently produces:

```
{"Data":[{"ProductId":1,"ProductType":"SomeType 1","Name":"Name 1","Created":"\/Date(1371022186643)\/"},{"ProductId":1,"ProductType":"SomeType 2","Name":"Name 2","Created":"\/Date(1371022186648)\/"},{"ProductId":1,"ProductType":"SomeType 3","Name":"Name 3","Created":"\/Date(1371022186648)\/"}],"Total":3,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}
```

I tried to use:

```
field: "Data.ProductId",
```

instead of:

```
field: "ProductId",
```

in the JavaScript code with no avail.

Comment: Is it correct that all `ProductId` are 1?

Comment: Please, would you mind editing the post and including a sample of the date being sent? It should look like `[{"ProductId":1,"ProductType":"SomeType 1","Name":"Name 1","Created":"2013-06-11T18:12:59.565Z"},{"ProductId":1,"ProductType":"SomeType 2","Name":"Name 2","Created":"2013-06-11T18:12:59.565Z"},{"ProductId":1,"ProductType":"SomeType 3","Name":"Name 3","Created":"2013-06-11T18:12:59.565Z"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use ToDataSourceResult you should use the ASP.NET MVC wrappers. More info is available in the documentation: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding

Comment: Thanks. I understand this. Would you mind rewriting the above code as mvc style but with expandable rows. This is something I never got to work via the mvc style, that's why I switched back to the 'html style'